# MPI barrier not blocking file write, flush and os.fsync

Tags: python, io, mpi, mpi4py, barrier

I have this test code which does the following:

Write a test message to a file > Barrier > Read the test message > Assert equal > Repeat.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
from mpi4py import MPI


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
loop = True


def main():
    global loop
    txt_write = 'buhahaha'

    with open('test', 'w') as f1:
        if rank == 0:
            f1.write(txt_write)

        f1.flush()
        os.fsync(f1.fileno())

    comm.barrier()

    with open('test') as f2:
        txt_read = f2.read()

    try:
        assert txt_read == txt_write
    except:
        print("Assertion error", txt_read, "!=", txt_write, 'rank=', rank)
        loop = False
    finally:
        comm.barrier()
        if rank == 0:
            os.remove('test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    while loop:
        main()
        if i % 1000 == 0 and rank == 0:
            print("Iterations:", i)

        i += 1
```

It works for a few 100 or 1000 iterations, but then at one point it reads an empty file and the assertion fails. Other answers had recommended use of `flush` and `os.fsync`, but that does not seem to help - it just makes the execution slower. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What file system do you use? Is this a single node or a cluster?

Comment: Doesn't opening a file as writeable usually truncate it to be empty?  So, aren't your threads racing between most of them truncating it to be empty and one is truncating it then writing a string to it?

Comment: @zulan ext4 filesytem on linux. I ran this code with 2 processes on a workstation.

Comment: @jschultz410 MPI barrier waits until the `write`, `flush`, `os.fsync` and finally the `__exit__` function calls, which closes the file. The issue is text remains in the I/O buffer waiting to be written. Most of the time this code works. When it does not, **all** threads read an empty file, not just `rank > 1` threads.

Comment: Depending on how much data you have there, I'd reconsider the architecture. If there is not that much data, I'd read it inside rank 0 and broadcast it.

Comment: @jadelord Maybe I'm missing something pretty fundamental here.  My understanding is that you have N processes (or threads) that are executing main() inside a loop where they synchronize on the barrier between the write and read portions of each iteration on a shared disk (and between each iteration too).  My comment was simply that opening a file like this `open(fname, 'w')` typically truncates the file to be empty (i.e. - writing to it) and there is no guarantee on the inter-ordering of writes between the competing processes all modifying the same file.  Am I way off base here?

Comment: OK that makes sense. So the `open` call by different processes simply creates multiple instances in the memory. So when `rank > 1` writes to it in the end of an iteration, it is an empty file :). Explains also why @mko's modification worked.

Comment: Oh good!  I felt like I might be taking crazy pills there for a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this, instead:

```
if rank == 0:
  with open('test', 'w') as f1:
    f1.write(txt_write)
    # as @jschultz410 correctly pointed out, 
    # we remove f1.flush() and f1.close()

comm.barrier()

with open('test') as f2:
  txt_read = f2.read()
```

Comment: You had indention issue. Part of code was just for rank 0 and part was for every rank. And, you were opening the same file with all ranks for writing.

Comment: I don't think it was indentation issue.  It was a logical issue.  It looks like you expected `open(fname, 'w')` to have no effect on the file.  Also, why do you have the readers open the file for writing at all?  Why not just have the rank 0 thread be the only one to open it for writing?  While the non-rank 0 threads just skip straight to waiting on the barrier and then read?

Comment: Which is exactly what @mko did in his code, now that I look more closely at it.  (Originally, I thought he had all of them opening and writing the same string to it, which also would have worked, but been pointlessly redundant / inefficient).

Comment: You can drop the explicit calls to `flush()` and `close()` since the `with` clause will invoke those implicitly too.  Good job @mko noting that the explicit `fsync()` is not needed because you have ordered all the opens+reads to be after the single write+close and the OS should respect and enforce that.

Comment: I agree with @jschultz410 there. To explain further why I did so there, I tried to emulate a [unittest case which was causing problems](https://bitbucket.org/fluiddyn/fluiddyn/src/e3d88e82e2eece3887a4847e25790e8dc6464f0c/fluiddyn/util/test/test_mpi.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#test_mpi.py-43). The test case is a for a function which by default prints by rank 0, and the stdout is redirected to a file to test this feature. I may need to think of a better test.

Answer (score 0):

The code resulted in a [**race condition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where all processes were opening the same file simultaneously. Thanks to @jschultz410 and @mko for identifying this logical error.

My solution for the code was to use a memory stream instead of a real file. Now, the *open, write* and *read* parts of the code becomes:

```
from io import StringIO

f1 = StringIO()
if rank == 0:
    f1.write(txt_write)

f1.flush()
comm.barrier()

txt_read = f1.getvalue()
```